# Scale texture (by Math Power node)

Tags: texturing, node-editor, mathematics

I experimented a bit with vector math and got this texture.

[image]

It is compressed at the top and stretched below. How can I get the opposite effect? I did so, but I do not think that is the right way.

[image]

Comment: You have done it the right way: by transforming assigning x,y,z → x,(1-t),z and trasforming t (=1-y) instead of y. I'm going to suggest closing this question as it's unlikely to be useful to others (and also because, as I said, you already have the correct solution)

Comment: Manipulating texture coordinates with math seems to have many uses in creating various effects as well as working with procedural textures. I think this can be useful and see no reason to close it.

Comment: I agree, this is useful. Additionally, the solution he has is not using his supplied value, and what the question was about, and what I'm looking for. Lol I have actually hit three dead-ends here because the topic criteria was not "useful" yet, knowing how to do these via formulas is incredibly useful, and powerful.